# arel, how to join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Given

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :order => 'name ASC'
end
```

Using the Rails 3 stack, how can I query for all categories that 'have' products?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```ruby
Category.joins(:products).select("distinct categories.*").all
```

Comment: Do you happen to know a good reference on what is possible with arel queries?

Comment: I take my knowledge from googling, reading Rails-elite blogs. Important thing: ActiveRecord differs much from pure Arel.

Answer (score 35):

In ARel (NOT ActiveRecord) we will do the following:

```
p = Arel::Table.new :products    # Base Rel-var
c = Arel::Table.new :categories  # Base Rel-var

predicate = p[:category_id].eq( c[:id] ) # for equality predicate

p.join(c)                   # Natural join
  .on( predicate )          # Equi-Join
  .group( p[:category_id] ) # Grouping expression to get distinct categories
  .project( c[:id] )        # Project the distinct category IDs of the derived set.
```

Comment: When you say "In ARel (NOT ActiveRecord)," what precisely do you mean? That we can't do this in a class derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`? This is confusing.

Comment: In all these examples I never see the final step folding the AREL query back into Rails to get real records. What to do with p now? You can call to_sql on it for sure but how to turn it into an ActiveRecord::Relation that will load records?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Just stick it in an AR where method. ARel just generates SQL.

Comment: The above is a join and can't be stuck in a where method.

Comment: For an arel that generates a SELECT (not just a where clause), you use `find_by_sql(arel_expression.to_sql)`. This will return an array of records, not a chainable ActiveRecord::Relation, but at least it gives you the results.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing is asking a different question here really. Here is that question, and its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442073/iterating-through-every-record-in-a-database-ruby-on-rails  Briefly, a good answer is to use `.all.each`, and loop (Using `find_by_sql` works, but is not a good answer)  That's a basic ActiveRecord thing, which is why people tend to leave out these next steps, when answering questions like this about ARel querying.

Answer (score 3):

Another, simpler, approach is to use the ActiveRecord query interface's `join` in conjunction with ARel for the conditional statement:

```
joins(:user)
.where(User.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{query}%"))
```

Generates the following sql in sqlite3:

```
"SELECT \"patients\".* FROM \"patients\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"patients\".\"user_id\" WHERE (\"users\".\"name\" LIKE '%query%')"
```

And the following sql in postgres (notice the ILIKE):

```
"SELECT \"patients\".* FROM \"patients\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"patients\".\"user_id\" WHERE (\"users\".\"name\" ILIKE '%query%')"
```

This allows you to join with simplicity, but still get the abstraction of the ARel matcher to your RDBMS.