# Iterating through every record in a database - Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, loops, rails-activerecord

n00b question. I'm trying to loop through every User record in my database. The pseudo code might look a little something like this:

```
def send_notifications

        render :nothing => true

        # Randomly select Message record from DB
        @message = Message.offset(rand(Message.count)).first

        random_message = @message.content

        @user = User.all.entries.each do
            @user = User.find(:id)

            number_to_text = ""

            @user.number = number_to_text #number is a User's phone number
            puts @user.number

        end

    end
```

Can someone fill me in on the best approach for doing this? A little help with the syntax would be great too :)

Comment: can we get a bit more background on what you are trying to achieve. Going through you user database this way seems a bit overhead

Comment: It's better if you get a basic knowledge in Ruby. You will not regret it , for sure . Anyway , tell us what is the purpose if the loop ?

Comment: Sending an SMS to every user in the the DB. 'number' = a User's phone number.

Comment: updated the post with all of the controller's code to give more context.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax to iterate over all User :

```
User.all.each do |user|
  #the code here is called once for each user
  # user is accessible by 'user' variable

  # WARNING: User.all performs poorly with large datasets
end
```

To improve performance and decrease load, use `User.find_each` ([see doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each)) instead of `User.all`. Note that using `find_each` loses the ability to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Also a possible one-liner for same purpose:

```
User.all.map { |u| u.number = ""; puts u.number }
```